# c# asynchronous server with beginReceive

Tags: c#, sockets

Hi stack overflow members.
I'm struggling with some simple code but I can't get it done.
I have this asynchronous server which waits for connections.

```
while (clientSocket.Connected)
{             
    try
    {
        clientSocket.BeginReceive(so.buffer, 0, 200, SocketFlags.None
                                  , new AsyncCallback(wait),so);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }                
}
```

where so(shorted StateObject) it's my class:

```
internal class StateObject
{
    public TcpClient client;
    public byte[] buffer;

    public StateObject()
    {
        buffer = new byte[200];
        client = new TcpClient();
    }
}
```

I use this class to put out the information on the callback function. However I get `the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full`.
I posted a short piece from the actual program.
One interesting issue, is that if I write:

```
while (clientSocket.Connected)
{             
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[200];
        clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 200, SocketFlags.None
                                  , new AsyncCallback(wait),so);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }                
}
```

it will work, but I will not be able to pull out the buffer from the asynchronous function(wait).
I'm struggling with this and I can't find answers.

Answer (score 4):

The while loop shouldn't be there, just call beginreceive after the endreceive.

This is a poor example, but may give you some ideas:

```
public class AsyncTCP
{

    public void StartReceive()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[200];
        clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 200, SocketFlags.None, (state) =>
        {
            int bytesReceived = clientSocket.EndReceive(state);

            // handle buffer.

            if(bytesReceived != 0)
                StartReceive();
        } ,so);
    }
}
```

If it's about getting the state within the EndReceive handler:

```
private void StartReceive()
{
    StateObject myState = new StateObject();
    myState.buffer = new byte[200];
    myState.client = _client; // or whatever

    myState.client.BeginReceive(so.buffer, 0, 200, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(wait),myState);

}

private void EndReceive(IAsyncResult result)
{
    StateObject myState = (StateObject)result.State;

    int bytesReceived = myState.client.EndReceive(result);

    // handle myState.buffer

    StartReceive();

}
```

I think there are better ways to do this, like:
- only constructing a receive buffer ones.
- put some packet header/data with lengths in it.

Good luck

Answer (score 4):

How about using some TPL functions. So your code can be simplified a lot

```
int readBytes  = await s.ReceiveTaskAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

This is the extension method `ReceiveTaskAsync`

```
public static class SocketExtensions
{
    public static Task<int> ReceiveTaskAsync(this Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(
                       socket.BeginReceive(buffer, offset, count, SocketFlags.None, null, socket),
                       socket.EndReceive);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
while (clientSocket.Connected)//checks connected
{             
    try
    {
        clientSocket.BeginReceive(so.buffer, 0, 200, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(wait),so);//says begin receive and continues to do endlessly
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }                
}
```

You've to call `BeginReceive` again only after you received the data.

Here's and example from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx) how to do that.

Comment: I was inspiring myself from msdn also, and my functions are looking almost exactly the same.I've removed the while loop, now I get "the i/o operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request" when the client it's connecting to server

Answer (score -1):

I resolved my previous problem(I just needed to remove the while loop, however I messed it up with some code from a synchronous server).
Now I have another problem, so I will use this same thread.
From what I've searched, and understood, you can open an asynchronous server with BecinAccept like this(main method):

```
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8082);

TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8082);           

server = tcpListener.Server;
server.Bind(ipEndPoint);
server.Listen(4);

server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(beginConnection), server);
```

Then:

```
static void beginConnection(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
            Socket s = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
            server = s.EndAccept(iar);

            server.Listen(4); // this line was initially absent
            server.BeginAccept(beginConnection, s);
        }
```

I want to be able to connect to this server multiple clients.
However, when I try to do this, only the first client connects itself.
The client it's a simple socket, which just echoes back from the server, what we read from the console.
I thought that since in the main method I've called server.Listen(4), I will be able to connect 4 clients.
Then I thought of calling recursively BeginAccept in the beginConnection method.
And last, I received the error, that I must call first the Listen method, so I added that too.
Still no luck.

Comment: You should create a new question for this, but the problem is that the socket you receive from the `s.EndAccept(..)` is a socket to the client, not the server socket it self. You're losing the original server socket. This should be: `Socket clientSocket = s.EndAccept(iar);` Next you could start a async receive on it. `clientSocket.BeginReceive(...., clientEndReceiveHandler, clientSocket);` Look over here: _Socket.EndAccept Method (IAsyncResult)_ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa7866.aspx

Comment: How could I lose the original server, when in the main method, I call: server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(beginConnection), server); from what I see I'm doing the same thing as in the link from msdn you have.

Comment: Using the `server.BeginAccept(` <- means you're accepting new connections on a server socket. `server = s.EndAccept(iar);` means you're storing the connected clientsocket (the result of the Accept method) into the server variable. So you lost the original server socket. Then you're trying to receive new connected sockets on your newly connected client sockets.