# Server/Client Socket Connection issue

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, tcp

First of all, what my Project should do if it would work:

1. Client written in C++ connects to Server coded in C#
2. When Connection was successfully, Client sends "0" to the Server to request a random String of Hexadecimals
3. If the Client recieved the Hexadecimals he will send "1" to the Server
4. Now the Client does some Stuff with the recieved Hexadecimalstring and then sends it back to the Server
5. if what the client did to the Hexadecimalstring was correct(Basic authing System) he returns "1" otherwise he returns "0"

> Note: The recieving/sending on Client/Server side works, i tested it before by just sending 1 to the Server and the Server returns 0 if the recieved String was 1

Now to my Coding:
Thats the Server Part written in C#:

```
private static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
private static List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
private const int PORT = 11111;
private static byte[] buffer = new byte[100];

private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
    int received;

    try
    {
        received = current.EndReceive(AR);
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client Disconnected! (Forced)");
        current.Close();
        clientSockets.Remove(current);
        return;
    }
    //That's how my Example before worked:
    /*byte[] recBuf = new byte[1];
    Array.Copy(buffer, recBuf, received);
    string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
    if(text != "" && text.StartsWith("0"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved: " + text);
        string send = "1";
        Console.WriteLine("Sending: " + send);
        Byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(send);
        current.Send(data);
        Console.WriteLine("Sended!");
        current.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        current.Close();
        clientSockets.Remove(current);
        Console.WriteLine("Client Disconnected!");
        return;
    }
    current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 1, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);*/
    //worked like a charm!
    //That's my new Solution, that doesn't work:
    byte[] recBuf = new byte[100];
    Array.Copy(buffer, recBuf, received);
    string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
    while (text != "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received Data: " + text);
        if (text.StartsWith("0") && text.Length < 32)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client requests Random HexString...");
            string rand = GetRandomHexNumber(32);
            Byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rand);
            current.Send(data);
            Console.WriteLine("Sended HexString! - " + rand);
        }
        if (text.StartsWith("1") && text.Length < 32)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client recieved the HexString!");
        }
        if (text.Length > 32 && !text.StartsWith("0") && !text.StartsWith("1"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Result recieved!");
            //here will be some authing process but for simplicity just return "1"
            byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1");
            current.Send(data);
            current.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            current.Close();
            clientSockets.Remove(current);
            Console.WriteLine("Client Disconnected!");
            return;
        }
        if (current.Connected)
            current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 100, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
    }
    if (current.Connected)
        current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 100, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
}

private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    Socket socket;

    try
    {
        socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        return;
    }

    clientSockets.Add(socket);
    socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 100, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
    Console.WriteLine("Client Connected!");
    serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
}

private void setupServer()
{
    serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT));
    serverSocket.Listen(0);
    Console.WriteLine("Server Started!");
    Console.WriteLine("Listening for Clients...");
    serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
}

private void CloseAllSockets()
{
    foreach (Socket socket in clientSockets)
    {
        socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        socket.Close();
    }

    serverSocket.Close();
}
```

setupServer(); gets launched on Console startup!
The C# part is the only problematic on the c++ side everything is fine!
I really hope somebody is able to help me now, since i didn't recieved any kind of help yet on this forum and i'm really in need for this to work and i'm sure here are plenty of programmers that could help me(maybe it's just a logical issue so every answer or comment is appreciated)
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: If you're unhappy with your question, delete it. Don't delete its content.

Comment: @molbdnilo if a question has a answer it can't be deleted! and i just didn't wanted to show others that maybe search how i did my server to see my code, thats, why i modified it...

Comment: @DamnDaniel, but they still may see the code in the revision history... I would suggest changing the question so that it 1) outlined the essence of your code (that `while` loop with `BeginReceive()` in it is mandatory; the details of you received message processing may be omitted) and 2) described its incorrect behaviour (I expect the app to get stuck in an endless loop after first message received). (To be continued...)

Comment: I personally consider this question as useful since it illustrates a common trap people [tend to](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18549174/4295017) fall into when start working with this Begin*/End* Async model. I would definitely vote up this question for this reason should it have more clear and probably concise wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
while (text != "")
{
    // .....................
    if (current.Connected)
        current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 100, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
}
if (current.Connected)
    current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 100, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
```

with

```
if (text != "")
{
    // .....................
    // Notice there's no BeginReceive() here!
}
if (current.Connected)
    current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 100, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
```

The function passed as `callback` paramater to `BeginReceive()` normally should not call `BeginReceive()` in a loop "until session is over". Instead it should call the `BeginReceive()` *only once* to pend another read operation if further data is expected (i.e. "session in not over").